# Java Apache POI -- Creating an iterator to find a date

Tags: java, excel, date, iterator, apache-poi

I am attempting to find the cell reference for a specific date in an Excel file.  The Excel is set up so that the "Date" header is in A1, and dates are included across the same row in B1, C1, etc.

I attempted to create an iterator to go through these dates and compare them to an input date.
I omitted some code below for conciseness.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
       formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
       Date date = formatter.parse(args[0]);

    // ............

    // iterator to find date
    int dateRef = 0; //logs column of date
    Date tempDate = null;
    // while loop to check the date contents of each cell
    while (dateRef < 1000) {    // random number inserted
        dateRef++;
        tempDate = cell.getDateCellValue();
        if (date == tempDate) {
            break; //beaks if contents are equal
        }
        cell = results.getRow(0).getCell(dateRef);  // else continue and iterate one cell
        }
}
```

When I run this, the iterator keeps going right up to column 1000.  I checked this with print statements.  Even though the cell is landing on the correct date, it does not recognize the input date and the cell date value as the same, and therefore does not break.

I know this may not be the most efficient way of doing things, so if you have more suggestions, let me know about them.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the == operator in this case.  I would try with [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) or [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) in your case in order to find the proper date.

See the Question: [*What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/642706)

Comment: This worked really well.  I am new to Apache, and java in general, so the compareTo() was unknown to me.  Thank you for your help.